# Displaying vectors with origin and direction in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

Would like to display direction vectors at defined locations in Google Earth. In a 3D tool direction vectors differ from a position vector (i.e. 2 geographical points connected via a line) that the displayed size is independant of the zoom level, just dependant on the aspect angle (projection).

Side mote: Finally I would like to display 3 direction vectors which span a orthoganal coordinate frame. So each "vector" would point in 3D Space.

Any solution existing? Or any idea of workaround for it?

I am familiar with KML and already reached my first goal to display a ground track and to highlight areas of interests using polygons. However I have found no solution for my request.

Answer (score 0):

You can create points with icon images that look like an arrow, and rotate them with the appropriate tags, like in the KML below. Try copy/pasting that into Earth Pro.

Note that in this example I used an easily available icon where the arrow points down, but you might want to use your own where the arrow points up, so that the icon heading matches the compass angle. Also, you can play with the icon hotspot tag, to define what part of the icon image is anchored at your point's lat/lon. In this case I used the center of the image, but you could use the origin or tip of the arrow if you wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>arrow icons with headings</name>

    <Placemark>
        <name>heading: 0</name>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>3</scale>
                <heading>0</heading>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>        
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-90,38</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
        <name>heading: 75</name>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>3</scale>
                <heading>75</heading>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-85,38</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
        <name>heading: 150</name>
        <Style>
            <IconStyle>
                <scale>3</scale>
                <heading>150</heading>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
            </IconStyle>
        </Style>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-80,38</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>    

</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I was not correct on how a "direction vector" I would like to display, corrected above, sorry for that. What is then missing in your solution is that the shape of the icon changes with respect to the aspect angle of the user.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I misunderstood.  So are you trying to position the vectors (lines/arrows) in 3D space?  Meaning give them a specific direction in not only the lat/lon plane, but also in elevation?  If so, I don't have a good way to do that except for constructing your own line strings with appropriate elevations on the vertices... though of course those would grow/shrink as the user zooms in/out.  I did notice that in my example KML, the 0 degree icon rotates with rotation of the earth, but the 2 with other angles defined keep their headings.  Maybe a bug?

Comment: Using your comment, I added one paragraph to my original question. Yes, vectors would be in 3d-space, speaking in KML-terms they have a "heading" and a "tilt". Interestingly your solution allows to "tilt" the icons, but they don't change wrt. users aspect angle.